# make the user inputs float value can keep the same format when I print it out

Tags: java

I use nextLine to read user's input and split by spaces.

And treat user's inputs as float.

However the output are not the same as the original user inputs.

How could I fix it?

## Output

```
Enter 2 floats divided by a space12.31 2213.12
you entered 12.310000 and 2213.120117 successfully
Process finished with exit code 0
```

## Expected output

```
Enter 2 floats divided by a space12.31 2213.12
you entered 12.31 and 2213.12 successfully
Process finished with exit code 0
```

## my source code

```
private static float[] getTwoFloats(){
    Scanner rd = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true){
        System.out.print("Enter 2 floats divided by a space");
        try{
            String toks[] = rd.nextLine().split(" ");
            if(toks.length==2){
                float[] rtnFloats = new float[2];
                for(int i=0; i < 2; i++){
                    rtnFloats[i] = Float.valueOf(toks[i]);
                }
                return rtnFloats;
            }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    float[] twoFloats = getTwoFloats();
    System.out.printf("you entered %f and %f successfully", twoFloats[0], twoFloats[1]);

}
```

Comment: That's rather a tall order, as you don't actually know what format the user used. For example, he could have used scientific notation. And all his fractional trailing zeros are going to disappear whatever you do. The best you can do is just print the original two strings at him, with no conversion at all, but it's unlikely to be of much use in general.

Answer (score -1):

You should convert the data type while you use it, for print out, just store the inputs as string.

```
private static String[] getTwoFloats() {
    Scanner rd = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter 2 floats divided by a space");
        try {
            String toks[] = rd.nextLine().split(" ");
            return toks;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] twoFloats = getTwoFloats();
    System.out.printf("you entered %s and %s successfully", twoFloats[0], twoFloats[1]);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter 2 floats divided by a space55.248 5465.5645
you entered 55.248 and 5465.5645 successfully
```

**=================UPDATE=====================**

For the worries of @HarshilSharma, we can do it as below.

```
public static class FloatObj {
    private float value; // Store original string for printing
    private String str; // Store value for calculation

    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}

private static FloatObj[] getTwoFloats() {
    Scanner rd = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter 2 floats divided by a space");
        try {
            String toks[] = rd.nextLine().split(" ");
            if (toks.length == 2) {
                FloatObj[] result = new FloatObj[2];
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    FloatObj floatObj = new FloatObj();
                    floatObj.setStr(toks[i]);
                    floatObj.setValue(Float.valueOf(toks[i]));
                    result[i] = floatObj;
                }
                return result;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FloatObj[] results = getTwoFloats();
    System.out.printf("you entered %s and %s successfully", results[0].getStr(), results[1].getStr());
}
```

Comment: So you would keep two pairs (String - float) in sync throughout the program and update String or float whenever the other changes? That's untidy.

Comment: @HarshilSharma This solution is essentially exactly the same as yours. As you don't understand you own solution you're not in much of a position to ofmend on others.

Answer (score -1):

Use `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.printf`.

```
System.out.println("you entered " + twoFloats[0] + " and " + twoFloats[1] + " successfully");
```

I'm not sure about why exactly does this work and whats the difference between the two but I'll investigate. Maybe someone with better understanding can explain?

Comment: I think that you didn't understand the issue, if I input 123.45000, the output will not print out '000'.